# Windows Server isn't saving user profile settings after logout

Tags: windows

The issue is happening in both Windows Server 2008 and Windows Server 2012 environments. Let's say I login to any server on my network with my domain credentials or any other domain user account, any changes while in the session get lost after the user logs out from the session (icons positions, windows settings, taskbar, wallpaper, clicking the "Server Manager" Don't show me this console at logon", registry changes and many other settings). The only things that Windows Server remembers between logins / logouts are physical files.

Comment: It almost sounds like you are using an account in the `Domain Guests` group. That is built to clear the profile on logoff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior is typical of an account in the `Domain Guests` group. It is built to clear the profile of the user every time they log off.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn579255(v=ws.11).aspx#BKMK_DomainGuests

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/940453/a-temporary-user-profile-is-created-every-time-that-you-log-on-to-a-windows-vista-based-computer-that-is-connected-to-a-domain

Comment: Just noting that the user could be a member of a group which in itself is a member of the `Domain Guests` group, and it won't be visible on the `Member Of` tab of the user account.